# Is it possible to prevent a multi line HeaderText in a DataGridView?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, header, width

When the length of the `HeaderText` property reaches a certain character limit and there is a space in the text, WinForms automatically inserts a link break in the header:

What I want:

```
+-----------------------+---
| Measurement Value (%) | ...
+-----------------------+---
```

What I get:

```
+-----------------------+---
| Measurement Value     | ...
|(%)                    |
+-----------------------+---
```

There is more than enough space to display all header cells without the lines breaks, but for whatever reason it is still inserted even when I set the `AutoSizeMode` to `HeaderCell`.

How can I prevent these line breaks, while still keeping the spaces in the `HeaderText`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle` property of the `DataGridView` has a boolean property called `WrapMode`. This is true by default. Make it false to set the required behaviour.

Answer (score 18):

You can not directly set it to false. The correct way of setting it to false is:

```
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False;
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to stop multiline text in DataGridView control then Wrap Mode should be false and set padding
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could either set the `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode` to `DataGridViewTriState.False` as the other answers already proposed

or

you could replace the spaces `\s` in your header string with non-breakable spaces `\u00A0`. The second solution has the benefit that you could set manual line breaks using `\n` in your header string and avoid auto wrapping. E.g.:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| A\u00A0very\u00A0long\u00A0first\u00A0Line\n |
| A\u00A0second\u00A0very\u00A0long\u00A0line  |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

The first solution is not allowing manual line breaks (everything is one line).